# Save email config in CodeIgniter and changing a setting when needed

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

Today I experimented with the email class in CodeIgniter. I have saved my email $config in `config/email.php` as per the documentation. And then I just use the email class as normal. So is it something like this:

**config/email.php:**

```
<?php
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '******',
        'smtp_pass' => '******',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
?>
```

**Some Controller:**

```
public function sendMessage(){
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('me@here.comk', 'My Name');
    $this->email->to("someone@somewhere.com");
    $this->email->subject('A test email from CodeIgniter using Gmail');
    $this->email->message("A test email from CodeIgniter using Gmail");
    $this->email->send();
}
```

With this setup, everything works fine, but now if **I wanted to change some settings how would I do that?** For example, I want to send the email from a different account in and part of the website: I need to be able to change the `smtp_user` and the `smtp_pass` fields. How would I do this? I want to avoid rewriting a whole new config array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the config in an array and **add the array when loading the email library in your controller**:

```
     $email_config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '******',
        'smtp_pass' => '******',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $email_config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('me@here.comk', 'My Name');
    $this->email->to("someone@somewhere.com");
    $this->email->subject('A test email from CodeIgniter using Gmail');
    $this->email->message("A test email from CodeIgniter using Gmail");
    $this->email->send();
```

If you want to change the config, just do the above and set the values of each parameter to whatever you want them to be via POST or however they're passed to the controller.

I'm not sure if you edited your question the first time around after I posted or if I just missed it, but I now see the 'I want to avoid rewriting a whole new config array' now. I'm not aware of any other way.

Comment: hi, I didn't edit my question and yes that's prety much what I want "I want to avoid rewriting a whole new config array' now"

Comment: Just pass the values you want to override, not the whole array

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the settings coming from config/email.php is possible. You need to `$this->load->library('email');` to bring in the settings from the config/email.php. Then you can create a new config array for the settings you want to override and call `$this->email->initialize($config);` to apply those settings.

**config/email.php:**

```
<?php
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '******',
        'smtp_pass' => '******',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
?>
```

**Some Controller:**

```
public function sendMessage(){
    $this->load->library('email');

    $config = Array(
        'smtp_user' => '******',
        'smtp_pass' => '******'
    );

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('me@here.comk', 'My Name');
    $this->email->to("someone@somewhere.com");
    $this->email->subject('A test email from CodeIgniter using Gmail');
    $this->email->message("A test email from CodeIgniter using Gmail");
    $this->email->send();
}
```